# There was a problem adding your media in powerapps

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, power-automate, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

Whenever i try to add an image in the Media of canvas powerapps, the below Error is coming

Error

"There was a problem adding your media in powerapps".

Please suggest some solution for this.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do other users occur the same issue?

Try to create a blank Canvas app in power apps:

[image]

Then upload and add the img to canvas to compare the result:

[image]

Comment: Hi julie,

I tried creating a sample canvas app and try to add the image there also same problem

Comment: Please help confirm if other users have the same problem.

Comment: Hi Julie,

My colleagues also facing the same issue while uploading the images but my client manager can able to apply, this issue is very strange because i am the owner of that app and he is the co-owner of that app :(

Comment: Please create a new service request in power apps admin center to check if there is something wrong on back-end side: https://admin.powerplatform.microsoft.com/support?l=en-US